# Node16 fs.createReadStream, ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js

I'm creating a file locally and then I nead to read it with

```
fs.createReadStream(realFilePath)
```

Where:

```
import * as path from 'path';
// more code
const realFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', nameFile);
console.log('realFilePath', realFilePath);
// realFilePath /Users/myuser/Documents/projects_2/myProject/06_023_0aetc....pdf
```

I can see the path there, and the file is actually in that location:

Any idea?

With node12 I had no problem, but I've just upgrade to node16 I had to add the `dirPath` to point directly to the complete path, in other case, files will try to read the current directory of the file and I'll get the same error
[image]

EDIT: I have put some code according to @Lind Du suggestion:

```
console.log('1) __dirname', __dirname);
const realFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', nameFile);
fs.access(realFilePath, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
  console.log(`${realFilePath} ${err ? 'does not exist' : 'exists'}`);
});
console.log('2) realFilePath', realFilePath);
```

The file exists.

[image]

Comment: What did you get when run ```fs.access(realFilePath , fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
  console.log(`${realFilePath } ${err ? 'does not exist' : 'exists'}`);
}); ```

Comment: Is your project using es modules or cjs? Could it be the use of `__dirname` in an ES context?

Comment: You show the use of static `import` (which implies an ESM module) and `__dirname`.  If this is an ESM module, then `__dirname` does not exist by default unless you manually calculated it.

Comment: If `realFilePath` shows 100% correctly in the console, then you probably have a permission issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, it's 100% correctly. In localhost (as the screenshot) and also on a pod on Kubernetes (`/app/thefilename.pdf`)

Comment: @LinDu ok, I'll update my question with that output.

Comment: Permissions, but I put the screenshot of the permission of the file, seems correct.

Comment: I put the screenshot of the permission of the file, seems correct: `-rw-r--r--` which is 644 (owner, group and public can read, I think that Read is the only permission that it's needed here)

Comment: Sidenote: you don't need `import * as path from 'path';`, just say `import path from "path";`. Not so sidenote: when using ESM there is no `__dirname__` global, so you need to find "the file's directory` using the `url` library and ESM's `import.meta.url`. (and you should be able to find how to get an ESM dirname equivalent by searching Stackoverflow just fine, plenty of folks already asked about this)

Comment: Why do you attach screenshots of output? Just put it in a codeblock like the rest of the code. You still haven’t answered whether your project is CJS or ESM.

Answer (score 0):

After the upgrade to node 16 I had to put in package.json this:

```
"overrides": {
  "fs-capacitor": "6.2.0"
},
```

Then the problem with relatives, absolute, etc, paths to file, among other while using `fs` dissapeared.